# Android disc space used by application

Tags: android

Is it possible to programmatically get disc space used by my application only? [StatFs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs.html) seems to be returning only general info.

The purpose is to check whether my application exceeds given disc usage threshold (in percents). To be more specific, I have sqlite table which acts like a queue where records are stored pretty frequently (1-60 per second). In normal conditions these records are sequentially removed as soon as they are delivered to a server, but in case the server is not reachable, I would like to detect situation when records take too much disk space and delete the oldest ones.

Comment: what are you storing in the database?

Comment: @blackbelt I am storing a record mostly with GPS data. Records should be sent to the server, but not too frequently, this is why I use queue and separate thread which reads from the table, sends records and remove them if they are delivered correctly.

Comment: so, string int worst case?

Comment: Yes, it's int, int, string, int.

Comment: If I were in you I would not worry too much about it. Still you can easily retrive the file path to the database through the context object (`getDatabasePath`), create a file object, and check its size (`File.length()`).